# How can I use CompareValidator for times without dates?

Tags: validation, asp.net-2.0, comparevalidator

When I enter *9:00* into the Start control, and *16:00* into Finish; the code below fails validation.

Does anybody know a way I can use the ASP.NET validator for times without the dates?

```
Start <asp:TextBox ID="txtStart" runat="server" /> (hh:mm)
<br />
Finish <asp:TextBox ID="txtFinish" runat="server" /> (hh:mm)
<br />
<asp:CompareValidator
    id="cpvFinish"
    ControlToValidate="txtFinish"
    ControlToCompare="txtStart"
    Operator="GreaterThanEqual"
    Type="Date"
    Display="Static"
    EnableClientScript="true"
    ErrorMessage="Finish time must be later than the start time."
    runat="server" />
```

PS-I know I can easily use CustomValidator instead, it just seems like something this validator should be able to handle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appearently cannot be done.

For the record; I used a custom validator.

EDIT: Here's my custom validator code in case anyone (i.e. alhambraeidos) needs it.  Please note, this code replaces my sample control names (txtStart & txtFinish) with actual names from my app (txtReady & txtClose).

```
try
{
    // parse & compare dates
    string randomDt = "01/01/2000 ";
    args.IsValid = DateTime.Parse(randomDt + txtClose.Text) > DateTime.Parse(randomDt + txtReady.Text);
}
catch(Exception /*ex*/)
{
    // exception is assumed to be invalid times entered
    args.IsValid = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change the Type property to String, it should work.

Comment: That was the first thing I tried.  But since '9' in '9:00' is greater than the '1' in '16:00', it fails validation.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to depend on the user to enter the zero.  I don't want to add any more client side js either.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Compare validator allowable types are:
Stinrg,
Integer,
Double,
Date (no time)
Currency